# I am getting junk when I try to print the new array when i return it from function

Tags: c

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int* divided_by(int* s1, unsigned int n1, int* s2, unsigned int n2)
{
    int *r =(int * )malloc (n1 * sizeof(int));
    if(!r)
    {
        printf("couldn't allocate memery");
        exit (1);
    }
    int flag=0;
    int i=0,j=0,c=0;
    while(i<n1)
    {
        while(j<n2)
        {
            if((*(s1+i) % *(s2+j)==0) )
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(flag==0) {
            *(r+c) = *(s1 + i);
            c++;
        }
        flag=0;
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    int s1[]={1,10, 5, 4, 21, 49, 24};
    int s2[]={2,3};
    int *r= divided_by(s1,7,s2,2);
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(r);i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",r[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the function should return the new array "r" that contains the elements that cant be divided by all the elements from the second array when i return the arry "r" and trying to print it in main i get junks such as 0 0 .c

Comment: What does this expression *(r+1) mean?

Comment: You only ever write to `r[1]`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i ment *(r++)

Comment: @am_sa In this case the original pointer will be lost.

Comment: @am_sa And why is the function called divided_by insetad of not_divided_by?:)

Comment: You should use a separate index into the `r` array, and then update that index as necessary. That way, `r` remains a pointer to the beginning of the array, which you can return to the user.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that could be a good change in the code :)

Comment: @am_sa The condition in the for loop for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(r)/4);i++) does not make a sense.

Comment: Also note that you need to inform the caller how many items were stored in the `r` array, since that number could be less than `n1`.

Comment: @am_sa sizeof( r ) is equivalent to sizeof( int * ). So neither information about the number of elements in the allocated array can be obtained such a way.

Comment: you should give your variables more meaningful names.

Comment: @am_sa And the function is declared incorrectly. It is unable to return two kinds of information: the address of the allocated array and the number of elements in the allocated array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i fixed the code by using separated index for the allocated array , and fixing the condition in the main function , the function return the address of the allocated array

Comment: @am_sa And how many elements of the allocated array are you going to output?

Comment: What is `divided_by` is supposed to achieve?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i assumed that every element could not be divided i will try to figure out a way to get the exact numbers without adding 0's to the output like in the example i have in this code i get the numbers and the rest 0 till the end of the allocated array

Comment: Instead of `*(s1+i)`, it is more common to write `s1[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your divided_by is working fine tho I would optimize it a bit to make it consume less memory and be faster.

Anyways the problem is your for loop in the main...

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(r);i++)
{
    printf("%d\t",r[i]);
}
```

You declared r as an int pointer which means that r shows the place of the first integer in the array. hence the sizeof(r) returns 8 (size of an int pointer, which is 8 bytes). In this specific example, your function divided_by returns a pointer containing 3 elements but you print 8 of them cuz of that, you get the 3 correct elements (1, 5, 49) and 5 junks.

A solution might be writing a function that calculates the length of your array for example...

```
int len(int *r)
{
        int len;

        len = 0;
        while (r[len])
                len++;
        return len;
}
```

Make sure that the system initializes not used memory in r to zero. Or use calloc() instead of malloc(). This will ensure that len() function works fine on any system.

And then you use this function in the condition of your for loop. Like this...

```
for(int i=0;i<len(r);i++)
{
    printf("%d\t",r[i]);
}
```

After this, you will get the desired output.

Comment: I think `len` might fail if no parameter is divisible, or if it compiled and run in a system that does not guarantee that memory is initialized to zero.

Comment: @azelcer You are right about a system that does not guarantee that memory is initialized to zero. Because of that I will recommend using calloc() instead of malloc().

Answer (score 1):

As many have noted, the main problem in your code is that you use `sizeof(r)` as if were the number of available items in the array. Since the return value must be the new array, you need to find a way to pass the number of items or signal the end. I would use a sentinel value of `0` at the end of the array (I assume nobody will pass a `0` to check if it is divisible). Other options include saving the length in the first position of the array.

I modified a little `divided_by` to make ir more efficient and cleaner: now it stops checking when it finds the first divisor. I also free in `main` the allocated memory in `divided_by`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* divided_by(int* s1, unsigned int n1, int* s2, unsigned int n2)
{
    int *r =(int *) malloc ((n1+1) * sizeof(int)); /* n+1 for the sentinal*/
    if(!r)
    {
        printf("couldn't allocate memery");
        exit (1);
    }
    int i=0, c=0;
    while(i < n1)
    {
        int j=0;
        while ((j < n2) &&  (s1[i] % s2[j])) /* once it failed, stop checking*/
        {
             j++;
        }
         if(j == n2)
         {
             r[c] = s1[i];
             c++;
         }
        i++;
    }

    r[c] = 0; /*sentinel */
    return r;
}

int main() {
    int s1[]={1,10, 5, 4, 21, 49, 24};
    int s2[]={2,3};
    int *r= divided_by(s1, 7, s2, 2);
    for(int i=0 ; r[i] != 0 ; i++) /* until we find the sentinel*/
    {
        printf("%d\t",r[i]);
    }
    free(r); /* Don't forget to release the memory*/
    return 0;
}
```